# Go Go Gadget Web Crawler

Tags: beginner, concurrency, go

In [*A Tour of Go*](http://tour.golang.org/#73), you are given the following problem:

> In this exercise you'll use Go's concurrency features to parallelize a
>   web crawler.
>
> Modify the `Crawl` function to fetch URLs in parallel without fetching
>   the same URL twice.

This is the code you're given

> ```
> package main
>
> import (
>     "fmt"
> )
>
> type Fetcher interface {
>     // Fetch returns the body of URL and
>     // a slice of URLs found on that page.
>     Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
> }
>
> // Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
> // pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
> func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
>     // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
>     // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
>     // This implementation doesn't do either:
>     if depth <= 0 {
>         return
>     }
>     body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
>     if err != nil {
>         fmt.Println(err)
>         return
>     }
>     fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
>     for _, u := range urls {
>         Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
>     }
>     return
> }
>
> func main() {
>     Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
> }
>
> // fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
> type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult
>
> type fakeResult struct {
>     body string
>     urls []string
> }
>
> func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
>     if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
>         return res.body, res.urls, nil
>     }
>     return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
> }
>
> // fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
> var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
>     "http://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
>         "The Go Programming Language",
>         []string{
>             "http://golang.org/pkg/",
>             "http://golang.org/cmd/",
>         },
>     },
>     "http://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
>         "Packages",
>         []string{
>             "http://golang.org/",
>             "http://golang.org/cmd/",
>             "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
>             "http://golang.org/pkg/os/",
>         },
>     },
>     "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
>         "Package fmt",
>         []string{
>             "http://golang.org/",
>             "http://golang.org/pkg/",
>         },
>     },
>     "http://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
>         "Package os",
>         []string{
>             "http://golang.org/",
>             "http://golang.org/pkg/",
>         },
>     },
> }
> ```

And this is the solution I came up with

```
type Job struct {
    url   string
    depth int
    done  chan bool
}

func dedup(fetcher Fetcher, ch chan Job) {
    seen := make(map[string]bool)
    for job := range ch {
        if _, ok := seen[job.url]; ok || job.depth <= 0 {
            job.done <- true
            continue
        }
        seen[job.url] = true
        go Crawl(job, fetcher, ch)
    }
}

func Crawl(job Job, fetcher Fetcher, q chan Job) {
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(job.url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        job.done <- true
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", job.url, body)
    ch := make(chan bool, len(urls))
    for _, u := range urls {
        u := u
        go func() { q <- Job{u, job.depth - 1, ch} }()
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(urls); i++ {
        <-ch
    }
    job.done <- true
    return
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    q := make(chan Job)
    go dedup(fetcher, q)
    q <- Job{"http://golang.org/", 4, done}
    <-done
}
```

All jobs go through `dedup`'s channel, so that a given URL is fetched only once. `dedup` kicks off a goroutine for each unique URL it sees, and the goroutine then adds URLs from that page back to the channel.

Go's way of thinking is new to me, so my main concerns are

- Is it idiomatic?
- Is it clear what's going on to someone who's familiar with Go?
- Is buffering the channels in this way necessary (or even helpful)?

Comment: @DaveC thanks for the feedback, but it should be posted as an answer, not in the comments.

Comment: doing that now… at first I thought I only had a one line comment

Comment: @DaveC not a problem. Even [short answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/short-answers-and-code-only-answers) should be posted as answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Your map is of booleans so you can replace `if _, ok := seen[job.url]; ok || bar` with `if seen[job.url] || bar`. The zero value (which is what gets returned for non-existing map lookups) of `bool` is `false`.
- It would be better to have `Crawl` do something like

  ```
  defer func() {
      job.done <- true
  }()
  ```

  immediately once only rather than sprinkle `job.done <- true` at all the right places and hoping you (and any future editors) don't ever miss any.
- Your `for` loop in `Crawl` should either just require the channel is sufficiently buffered (as it currently is) and not bother with goroutines, or the whole for loop should be put into a single goroutine (and then you don't need any channel buffering).
- `for i := 0; i < len(urls); i++` should be just `for i := range urls` (or since you don't need `i` just `for _ = range urls`).
- You seem to be using `Jobs.done` like `sync.WaitGroup`.

  You could just have a single wait group that keeps track of outstanding jobs. Your `main` would make sure to call `wg.Add(1)` before sending it's first job and before it then does `wg.Wait()`. Mostly everywhere you do `job.done <- true` would then be just `wg.Done()`. You'd just need to make sure that your crawler did `wg.Add(len(urls))` before it did `wg.Done()` to make sure the wait group count could never accidentally fall to zero too early.
- Although having dedup check the depth is probably still a good idea, it's easy and trivially to do it in the crawl function and save some effort.

You code modified with the above points:

```
type Job struct {
    url   string
    depth int
}

func dedup(fetcher Fetcher, ch chan Job, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    seen := make(map[string]bool)
    for job := range ch {
        if seen[job.url] || job.depth <= 0 {
            wg.Done()
            continue
        }
        seen[job.url] = true
        go Crawl(job, fetcher, ch, wg)
    }
}

func Crawl(job Job, fetcher Fetcher, q chan Job, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(job.url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Crawl failure:", err) // TODO: something better with errors
        return
    }
    log.Printf("Crawl: found %s\t%q\n", job.url, body)

    if job.depth <= 1 {
        return
    }

    wg.Add(len(urls))
    for _, u := range urls {
        q <- Job{u, job.depth - 1}
    }
}

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(1)

    q := make(chan Job)
    go dedup(fetcher, q, wg)
    q <- Job{"http://golang.org/", 4}
    wg.Wait()

    // We close q here so that the dedup goroutine
    // will finish. This isn't strictly needed here
    // since we're main and everything gets stopped
    // when we return; but that wouldn't be the case
    // if we were some other function in a long lived
    // program.
    close(q)
}
```

And runnable on the playground (by including the Go tour stuff):
http://play.golang.org/p/cuY3PZdQmI

(For comparison: your original code is also [runnable on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Zovub8KdL-).)